# in magento2 add selected products throught checkbox to add to cart

Tags: magento2

I have checkbox on wishlist page in magento 2 and add to cart button now when i select checkbox that items should add to cart on button click on wishlist page

Comment: Could you please share some code of how you implemented the checkbox? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have added checbox and add to cart button now i have do that selected checkbox products should add to cart using knout js